# PHP: как правильно экранировать кавычки, если они, вместе со всей строкой в значении переменной?

Tags: php

До "return" функция благополучно возвращает и $this->name и $attrsStr.

А вот в склеенном виде значение уже не возвращается.

```
public function open(): string
    {
        $attrsStr = $this->getAttrsStr($this->attrs);

        $a = $this->name;
        $b = $attrsStr;
        $v = $a.$b;
        print_r('привет');
        return "<$v>";
    }
```

В дебаггере что-то очень много кавычек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверное это из-за экранирование, но если я пытаюсь добавить слеши вот так: `$b = addslashes($attrsStr);` или вот так: `return "\<$v>"\;`, то все равно ничего не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно экранировать? У меня WSL 2, так что это не может быть вызвано Windows..

**Результат добавления пробела:**

```
 $a = $this->name;
    $b = $attrsStr;
    $v = $a . $b;

    return "<$v>";
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуте пробел поставить до точки и после

Comment: А что именно вы пытаетесь экранировать и зачем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Зачем: функция open() не возвращает значение. Подумал, что причина в кавычках внутри href "a href=""". Экранировать пытаюсь именно их, чтобы зарабатало, что функция вернула занчение.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попробовал пробелы добавить, результат приложил к вопросу внизу..

Comment: Может быть всё же оно возвращает что нужно, просто вы не видите, т.к., например, в линке нет текста. Вы бы взяли, да посмотрели исходный код страницы........... кстати, в данном случае у вас во-первых будет `<ahref...` что уже неверно (или я недосмотрел) и во-вторых - нет закрывающего тега..... ну и текста тоже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский забыл добавить принтерю return, поэтому у меня не ссылка должна появиться, а строка html. если я, к примеру так делаю: $attrsStr = $this->getAttrsStr($this->attrs);
        return "<$attrsStr>"; то у меня на экран выводится < href="">, а вот если так попробую:  $attrsStr = $this->getAttrsStr($this->attrs);
        return "<$this->name$attrsStr>", то уже не выведется ничего..

Comment: "<$this->name$attrsStr>", то уже не выведется ничего.  ---- потому что это невалидная конструкция, которую интерпретатор не понимает.... можно попробовать вот так `"<{$this->name}{$attrsStr}>"`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да вы правы, в исходном коде нашел ссылку.. благодарю вас! <a href=""></a>

Comment: а я знааааааал)) знааааал))

Comment: ))))))))))))))))))))))))))